# JDBC Connection URL to Apache Phoenix on Azure HDInsight

Tags: java, azure, jdbc, azure-hdinsight, apache-phoenix

I am using the folloing URL to connect via JDBC to Apache Phoenix on Azure's HDInsight, which basically consists of the Zookeeper Server as per the Ambari Dashboard.

`jdbc:phoenix:zk0-apache.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.tx.internal.cloudapp.net,zk1-apache.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.tx.internal.cloudapp.net,zk2-apache.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.tx.internal.cloudapp.net:2181:/hbase-unsecure`

Below is the stack trace to the exception.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: zk0-apache.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.tx.internal.cloudapp.net: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.<init>(StaticHostProvider.java:61) ~[zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:3.4.10-39d3a4f269333c922ed3db283be479f9deacaa0f]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:445) ~[zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:3.4.10-39d3a4f269333c922ed3db283be479f9deacaa0f]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:380) ~[zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:3.4.10-39d3a4f269333c922ed3db283be479f9deacaa0f]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.checkZk(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:144) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.<init>(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:131) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:143) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:181) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:155) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.<init>(ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.java:43) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveZooKeeperWatcher(ConnectionManager.java:1737) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:104) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:945) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:721) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [na:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [na:1.8.0_172]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:439) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:348) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:144) [hbase-client-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.phoenix.query.HConnectionFactory$HConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(HConnectionFactory.java:47) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:425) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.access$400(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:267) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2515) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2491) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2491) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:255) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:150) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:221) [phoenix-core-4.14.0-HBase-1.4.jar:4.14.0-HBase-1.4]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) [na:1.8.0_172]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) [na:1.8.0_172]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154) [spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145) [spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) [spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) [spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) [spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:123) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceInitializer.isEnabled(AbstractDataSourceInitializer.java:74) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceInitializer.initialize(AbstractDataSourceInitializer.java:54) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1737) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at com.myntra.asn_api.AsnApiApplication.main(AsnApiApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
```

Anyone here working on Phoenix on Azure HDInsight?

What is the JDBC url(for both thick and thin clients) to be used to connect to Phoenix on Azure HDInsight?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging, the JDBL URL is fine and found there were two issues with Azure HDI setup:

1. Zookeeper Server was not started
2. Zookeeper port(2181) is not open

**1.** Zookeeper Server is not automatically started if you are using Azure HDI,
   it has to be started by running the below command

```
 `./usr/hdp/2.xxcx/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start`
```

The above command starts the Zookeeper server in standalone-mode. If you need to start the Zookeeper in cluster-mode, you need to add the Zookeeper Server FQDNs(server.{1..n}) to the `./usr/hdp/2.xxcx/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg` file if there are not present already.

```
maxClientCnxns=50
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181

server.1=zk0-apache.xxxxxxxxx.tx.internal.cloudapp.net:2888:3888
server.2=zk1-apache.xxxxxxxxx.tx.internal.cloudapp.net:2888:3888
server.3=zk2-apache.xxxxxxxxx.tx.internal.cloudapp.net:2888:3888
```

You need to stop and start the zkServer after the configuration changes.
[More info on Zookeeper documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup).

**2.** Azure HDI Cluster, by default, is created inside a network which doesn't expose your cluster ports(eg. 2181, 8765) to the public. You need to have a Virtual Network created as explained in [this artcile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-extend-hadoop-virtual-network) and create the HDI cluster inside this network. Through the network, you will be able to open the desired ports.